# SQL query question - tricky one

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have two tables, one with a single payment information and an id (LFN), on the other hand there are payment positions:

single payment:

[image]

payment positions:

[image]

goal is to get a table like this:

[image]

with our_recno there is one match, through customer id i can find all associated positions. I do this with a subquery. The best solution I get is this:

[image]

Do you have an idea how I can repeat the LFN Number instead of getting NULL?

Thank you very much for your ideas.

Comment: I don't see the problem, you are almost there. You could use the isnull function to provide a substitute value when the field is equal to null. But without seeing the data, sql, table structure etc - can't say much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build a bridge, which you should **already** have, so you should think about your design

The only useful and not redundant information that has the table payment is LFN and to be honest put this into the payment_positions, every information you want you can get from payment_positions then:

```
CREATE TABLE [payment] (
  [LFN] INTEGER,
  [OUR_RECNO] INTEGER,
  [TOTAL] FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO [payment]
  ([LFN], [OUR_RECNO], [TOTAL])
VALUES
  ('1234', '36622016', '71.89');
GO
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
CREATE TABLE [payment_positions] (
  [OUR_RECNO] INTEGER,
  [CUSTOMER] INTEGER,
  [TOTAL] FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO [payment_positions]
  ([OUR_RECNO], [CUSTOMER], [TOTAL])
VALUES
  ('36617800', '2566303', '47.34'),
  ('36622016', '2566303', '10.51'),
  ('36625936', '2566303', '14.04');
GO
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT [CUSTOMER],[OUR_RECNO] 
FROM [payment_positions] 
WHERE [OUR_RECNO] IN (SELECT [OUR_RECNO] FROM [payment] )
```

```
CUSTOMER | OUR_RECNO
-------: | --------:  
 2566303 |  36622016
```

```
SELECT r.[LFN], ac.[OUR_RECNO], ac.[CUSTOMER], ac.[TOTAL]
FROM [payment] AS r
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [CUSTOMER],[OUR_RECNO] FROM [payment_positions] WHERE [OUR_RECNO] IN (SELECT [OUR_RECNO] FROM [payment] )) AS t1
ON r.[OUR_RECNO] = t1.[OUR_RECNO]
INNER JOIN [payment_positions]  AS ac
ON ac.[CUSTOMER] = t1.[CUSTOMER]
```

```
 LFN | OUR_RECNO | CUSTOMER | TOTAL
---: | --------: | -------: | ----:
1234 |  36617800 |  2566303 | 47.34 
1234 |  36622016 |  2566303 | 10.51 
1234 |  36625936 |  2566303 | 14.04
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3a67fe468d5aec45710151a7fd2579a)*